Does any surjective morphism from an affine hypercovering of the pro-etale site to a w-contractible one admit a section?
I am reading the paper "The Pro-Etale Topology for Schemes" by Bhatt-Scholze and am trying to understand Remark 4.2.9. Unless otherwise said, all results I reference are from this paper. Morphisms of schemes are assumed to be weakly etale, including the degree-wise morphisms of hypercoverings.
The way I understand the statement of the remark is: Given two w-contractible hypercoverings (i.e. hypercoverings of the pro-etale site that are degree-wise w-contractible, I will write w-c from now on) $W_{\bullet}$ and $W'_{\bullet}$ are homotopy equivalent. By this I mean that there exists simplicial morphisms $f\colon W_{\bullet} \to W'_{\bullet}$ and $g\colon W'_{\bullet} \to W_{\bullet}$ such that $fg$ and $gf$ are (simplicially) homotopic to the respective identities.
Recall that an affine scheme $W$ of the pro-etale site of a base scheme is called w-c if any surjective morphism $A \to W$ from an affine scheme admits a section (see Definition 1.4). I assumed it was possible to extend the existence of such sections to hypercoverings (see next paragraph for a precise statement) and from there on managed to prove that any simplicial morphism $W_{\bullet} \to W_{\bullet}$ with $W_{\bullet}$ a w-c hypercovering is homotopic to the identity.
By "extending the existence of sections to hypercoverings" I mean: Given a w-c hypercovering $W_{\bullet}$ and a simplicial morphism $f\colon A_{\bullet} \to W_{\bullet}$ that is  degree-wise surjective, there is a section $s\colon W_{\bullet} \to A_{\bullet}$.
Actually a slightly weaker result suffices: It is enough if the composite $fs$ is homotopic to the identity, i.e. I only need a section up to homotopy.
I want to use the construction result in SGA4 (Expose Vbis, Proposition 5.1.3) to construct the section. As far as I can see I run into two problems:

On degenerate simplices I have to use the sections from lower degrees. This can be fixed by assuming the hypercovering $W_{\bullet}$ to be split. Since any hypercovering admits a split refinement this should not be too much of a problem.
On the faces of an $(n{+}1)$-simplex the section from degree $n{+}1$ has to be compatible with the one from degree $n$. This is where I run into problems.

I don't see why this can be guaranteed. As far as I can tell the (to me) problematic part of the construction of w-c contractible objects in the proof Lemma 2.4.9 is the choice of the section $s$ at the end of the proof of Lemma 2.4.8.
My questions are:

Is my understanding of the formulation of Remark 4.2.9 correct?
Does someone have a suggestion on how to fix my problem with extending the existence of sections to w-c hypercoverings?

I have also tried a different approach, but the strategy above seems like the natural one to me.
